# Get an error to the console: "Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined" when sorting and filtering

Tags: angular

I'm new to `Angular`, so don't be too strict. I have a page with a list of all my clients, and what I want to do - is to filter them by the `name`, and sort by `id`. To make it work, I've created two `pipes`, one is for filtering, and the other one is for sorting. Both `pipes` are included into `appModule`. Here they are:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
  pure: false
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], term): any {

    return term ? items.filter(item => item.name.indexOf(term) != -1) : items;
  }

}
```

and

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sortBy',
  pure: false
})

export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform{

  transform(items: any[], sortedBy: string): any {
    return items.sort((a, b) => {
      return a[sortedBy] - b[sortedBy]
    })
  }

}
```

In the view I implement it like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="term" [(ngModel)]="term">

<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let client of clients | filter: term | sortBy: 'id'; let i = index"
    <td>{{ client.name }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the error I have in the console:
[image]

But everything seems to be working fine in the view, it filters and sorts, the only thing is that there are errors in the console. How can I get rid of that errors? Thanks.

Comment: Check if the `items` array is null before sorting.

Comment: can you provide the code in the .ts file, where the clients is declared and get the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point in the execution the `clients` is undefined, which causes the error in the console.

You can prevent this by checking for it in your pipe before calling the sort method.

```js
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sortBy',
  pure: false
})

export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform{

  transform(items: any[], sortedBy: string): any {
    if (!items) { return items; } // <-- Code to make sure the items is not undefined
    return items.sort((a, b) => {
      return a[sortedBy] - b[sortedBy]
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped, as soon as I'll be able to accept the answer, I will.